# Git added files in ignore after I had done git add, now how to remove?

Tags: git

I had ran git add . and then saw it was a huge file.
I created a file .gitignore

```
/live-1
/live/application/report_images
/live/application/report_images_old
/live/application/report_pdfs
/live/application/order_pdfs
/sig
/live/notused
```

The problem is since the first add was made it's still tracking the files.
I tried running (as recommended by SO)

```
git rm -r --cache .
```

But this hangs.
Also tried individual directories like

```
git rm -r --cache live-1
```

This also hangs
How can I force it to recognize the ignore files?

Comment: Try `--cached` (with a “d”).

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't commited, you need to reset them. `git reset blah blah`

Comment: By this you mean reset each file?  Or directory?

Comment: Only what you added and that you don't want to be added and therefore started ignoring.

Comment: I did it and in example git reset /live/notused which is a directory I don't want to track.  Then I ran git status and it says nothing to commit.  @eftshift0